# I have a general question about learning woodworking for a still somewhat beginner!

Tags: woodworking

So I am a college student and my major is woodworking, I enjoy it but I haven't really learned the simple things, I know a lot about table saw, routers, band saw, etc, but when it comes out to simple things like knowing when to use certain screws and which wood fits best with my project.
Now I'm the only girl in my major, and I get along with all the guys well but I hate to always have to ask them every time silly questions like these. They are more experienced than I am and I would love to learn more about basics I guess. My question is, how can I learn more about things like this? I don't want to just google each time, are there good sites or books that have mostly everything all summed up? anything you guys recommend?

Comment: One _fantastic_ site is [Wood Working SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/).  It's in beta, but there's a lot of good advice over there.

Comment: OJAIT, you might be supprised how willing some are to share thier knowledge, if you see someone in class helping others strike up a conversation, worst case you make a new firend ( I understad it may be different for a Lady so I may be showing my age there)

Comment: As JPhi1618 says, [Woodworking SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/) is a good place to ask questions. Another source I find useful (and fascinating) is Youtube - search for Paul Sellers, The English Woodworker, Matthias Wandel, Frank Howarth, April Wilkerson, Darbin Orvar and check the "related channels" on their Youtube homepages.

Comment: I wish I had learned younger that asking questions is a good thing. Asking well thought out questions is a sign of intelligence. Your instructors might be good resources for reference materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In no particular order, some suggestions, you've probably fond many....

[Fine Woodworking](http://finewoodworking.com) - magazine / ezine, tons to learn in the articles and even the ads!

[Woodweb](http://www.woodweb.com/) - great site for info about, you guessed it, wood.

[The Wood Database](http://www.wood-database.com/) - ditto.

[The Woodsmiths Shop](http://www.woodsmithshop.com/) - PBS woodworking show, free plans online, lots of good basic info

[The Woodwrights Shop](http://www.pbs.org/woodwrightsshop/home/) - another PBS woodworking show, focused on primitive methods

[Woodworker.com](http://woodworker.com/) - one of the many woodworking supplies you can find online, don't underestimate how much you can learn just browsing sites / catalogs - half the battle is knowing what's out there.

[Book:  The Mechanical Properties of Wood](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/12299/12299-h/12299-h.htm)

[Book:  Woodwork Joints](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21531/21531-h/21531-h.htm)
- free on Project Gutenberg, a couple old books about wood, there are more on gutenberg.org if you dig - old stuff, but much of the material is still relevant.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! These are amazing! Will be looking into these! Thanks to everyone else who answered too!

Answer (score 0):

Practice, practice, practice is the best way of learning and retaining knowledge. The more time you actually do a task the more adept you become. Start a project at home and build on when you have free time. There are many publications available on wood working (Fine Woodworking by Tauton Press is one). Reading and doing should be your mantra.

Answer (score -1):

the best way to learn woodworking and carpentry is by making things, making mistakes and making them again.  the machine tools in carpentry are the easy things to learn.  any monkey can use a router or drill press.  the artisanal craftsmanship comes from knowing how wood functions in a system.  my advice would be to go find the oldest woodworking shop.  then go find the oldest, crotchiest  old crank of a carpenter that is there and then beg and plead for him to let you hang around.  do anything he asks you to do, even if it seems like a waste of your time.  glue yourself to him and don't listen when he tells you to go away.  bring him some cookies or beer regularly.  its the old guys that can teach you the most.  youtube can teach you g-code or which carbide machines ipe the best, but its the old guys that can teach you about grain and joint design and how to use a handsaw.  I have to hire and fire a dozen "carpenters" every year because all they can do is "machine" wood like its an aluminum ingot.  carve things.  use a hand plane.  chop trees down with axes and and mill them into lumber yourself. you have to hear the sound of one hand chiseling.

Comment: Capitalization, punctuation, and paragraphs go a long way to make your answer clear and easy to read.  The "wall of text" effect without them is hard to parse.

Comment: I appreciate the critique of my writing, however, I do not subscribe to the old school grammar and etiquette of hand written prose.  In this day and age, it is abundantly clear that the absurd rules of yesteryear that once governed how one wrote, are quickly being thankfully forgotten by the millennial generation.  Capitalization, indenting, etc., are all being purposely left behind in favour of the speed and diction of the newer technologies supplanting parchment and quill.  I can do so if I wish to, but I do not have any desire to keep that paradigm alive and well.  Viva la Revolution!

Comment: You said you wanted to increase your rep in a comment on another question the other day, so just helping out.  The speed of reeding an answer is more important than how long it takes to write.  Regardless of how quick it is to write, a block of text is always harder to read than complete, delimited sentences.  This forum is "write once, read many", so you should do everything you can to make yourself clear.  Clear, well formatted answers will _always_ get more up-votes, but the choice is yours.

Comment: you must have me confused with someone else, as I have no interest in reputation increases (whatever that means).  I only joined two days ago to ask a question about a gas furnace.  I have been answering questions to make sure I am honouring our implied social contract.  however, as a newbie to forums in general, there are, I am sure,  thing to learn.  in that vein, what does "write once, read many" mean?  and whats with all the badges, privileges and points and stuff I keep getting alerts about?  is that just part of the microcosmic caste system of the forum, or does it mean something real?

Comment: Back and forth like this belongs in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement).  Maybe I did mix you up with someone else.  Use "@JPhi1618" to direct a message to me in chat.

Comment: How ever he wants to post an answer, and with the accuracy of this one, it should not have been down voted. Any quality answer that shows knowledge with the question but lacks punctuation should be commented on not down voted.